# How to Pan a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying for a while now to get a simple pan of a div to work, I however can not seem to get it to 100%. It partially works with bugs.

```
$("#view_point").mousedown(function(e) {
    start_x = e.pageX;
    start_y = e.pageY;
    e.preventDefault()
    //On Click set start x and y vars
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    temp_x = e.pageX;
    temp_y = e.pageY;
    e.preventDefault();
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    temp_x = Math.abs(temp_x - start_x);
    temp_x = Math.abs(temp_y - start_y);

    console.log(temp_x + " - " + temp_y);

    //Animate the map
    $("#tiles").animate({
        marginTop: '-' + temp_x,
        marginLeft: '-' + temp_y
    }, 50);
});​
```

How do I go about making a pan script that will pan inside a div that has its overflow property set to hidden.

Comment: Do you happen to have the HTML/CSS available? It would be good to see how "view_point" and "tiles" are related.

Comment: This is not an easy task, you will most likely end up with even more bugs as you progress. There are plenty of scripts you can use such as http://aino.github.com/pan.js/. If you still want to do it yourself from scratch, maybe you can isolate each problem you are having and ask specifically around that?